# Why do I get a blank page when I click on links that point to '/' with my react router setup?

Tags: reactjs

This is essentially how I have it set up:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Router>,
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
    )
})
```

```
const App = function(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <Navigation />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </>
    )
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout"

const Home = function (props) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            The Home Component.
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

So here's what happens.

The site loads fine initially. I can see "This is the home component" appear on the page when I go to `localhost:3000`. But when I try to click on a link that points to just "/", the result is a completely blank page. If I refresh while the blank page is present, then a refresh will make the content appear again and appears as if it's loading properly. But once I click a link with the `href="/"` it's just a blank page.

This is my Navigation component (just a simple bootstrap nav, basic links with just href="/"...):

```
const Navigation = function (props) {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div className="container">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Langsite</a>

                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">

                    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item active">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

Comment: Don't use a regular `<a>` tag, use instead the `<Link>` component provided by react router: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link

Answer (score 0):

```
const Navigation = function (props) {
return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div className="container">
            <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">Langsite</Link>

            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">

                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
)
```

}

This can solve your problem